# How can I match a tab not at the beginning of a line?

Tags: regular-expressions

In Emacs, when using `M-x replace-regexp`, how can one specify matching a tab which is not at the beginning of a line? I know how to match a tab which is at the beginning of a line by using `^`, but don't know how to do the opposite.

Answer (score 3):

When searching you can do: `C-u C-s . TAB`
IOW the regular expression uses `.` instead of `^`.

The regexp pattern `.` matches "any character" with the notable exception of the line separator character (aka LF), so `.a` is a regexp that matches an `a` preceded by a character that's not a line-separator, hence an `a` that's not at the beginning of a line.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain what the key means?

Comment: Can `.` in `.a`  match any character including `a`? So can match `aa` at the beginning of a line?

Comment: @Tim: Yes, indeed.  If you want to skip all lines that start with `a`, then you need something like `^[^a\n]+a`.

Comment: Does emacs' regex support `\n`?

Comment: @Tim: Emacs's regexps accept the LF character like any other character, yes.  When typing a regexp at the minibuffer you can insert an LF character with `C-j`, when typing a regexp in Elisp code (i.e. inside a string) you can use `\n` to insert an LF character into the regexp.

Comment: When typing a regexp at the minibuffer  can I insert an LF character with `\n`? when typing a regexp in Elisp code (i.e. inside a string), can I use `C-j` to insert an LF character into the regexp?

Comment: @Tim: These are getting off-topic.  Make them new questions.